# RAID 1 - What happens if I disconnect both disks?

Tags: raid, raid-1, connection

I'm trying to install windows on a new SSD, and I'm having problems getting it to work correctly.  I've read that it's good to disconnect all other drives and do a format and clean install.

Only problem is that I have 2 disks in a RAID 1 configuration. What happens if I just disconnect these drives, install on the new SSD, and then reconnect the two drives?

Comment: Your title says "RAID 1", your question "RAID 0" -- which is it? Also what sort of RAID is this? Hardware (which controller/model)? Software (which OS/software)?

Comment: You *do* know the pitfalls of using RAID 0, correct?

Comment: Good call, sorry about that.  It's RAID 1.

Comment: By the way, I'd like to just take them out of RAID, but when I go to the utility and try to do that, it says it will be erased.  Does that mean it will erase my data??  Also, I'm doing HW RAID controlled by the mobo (Gigabyte GA-P35-DS3R v1.0).

Answer (score 2):

You'll be OK. As soon as a RAID0 array goes into degraded mode, it's taken offline. Once both disks are present, it will go back online and things will continue nicely.

However, RAID 0 is very dangerous, so if you *do* lose all your data, well...

---

Ok, so if you're running RAID 1, then two things can happen:

1. Take both disks out at the same time (while the machine is off), and then put them both back at the same time (while it's off)
2. Take one disk while the machine is off, or, take the disks out one at a time while the system is running

In situation #1, then the machine will just think that the array is no longer present and will skip it (it might also present an error message). When both of the disks are put back, the array will just come back online.

In case #2, the 2nd disk will need to be re-built from the 1st when it is re-inserted because they're no longer in "lock step" (for lack of a better term).

---

You have a comment stating you want to take them out of RAID. Normally, you can just destroy the array in the controller and the data will live on, but you've said that the array is going to delete your data.

What I would do in that case, is just attach them to some non-RAID ports, or, unplug the disks, delete the array, and then just plug them back in. If it's a cheapo RAID controller (sounds like it is), it will just treat the two disks as normal disks.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say RAID 1.  I'm mirroring to back up data.  I set it up a couple of years ago, and I know (now) that RAID is not a backup solution.  I'm in the process of changing that now! :)

Comment: Thanks for the details.  I'm currently transferring all data to another driver to ensure I don't lose anything.  Then I'm going to play around with it and see what happens.  I'll report back the results.  :)